# Jupyter run all - then pause for choice to continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to add some Dropdown widgets in my jupyternotebook, then Run all. The program should pause at the Dropdown widgets to wait for me to choose and confirm before it can continue to run

I want to do this rather than keep pressing Shift+Enter

The structure is something like this:

`cell1`

`cell2`

```
afill = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['sector 1',
             'sector 2'],
    value='sector 1',
    description='Choose sector:')

weight = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['none',
             'weight'],
    value='none',
    description='Choose weight/not:')

display(afill, weight)

confirm = None
while confirm != 'y':
    confirm = input("""Select Dropdown and Type "y": """)
```

`cell 3`

`cell 4`

I tried several options to work around this including using loop `while` + `input` but so far unsuccessful.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but `input()` can be good for text scripts in console/terminal and it may not work on web page. I think it may need to reformat all code and use some Button which runs function with another code.

Comment: @furas: you are correct, using `input()` alone can solve. The only drawback is to type which I don't prefer. It is better if can have a `dropdown`